# Is the orthogonal vector of eigenvector still a eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the orthogonal vector of  eigenvector still a eigenvector?

I mean,if i found two eigenvectors, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ , for $\lambda =2 $,
and i calculate the orthogonal vector of $\vec a$ , named $\vec c$,by using Gram-Schmidt .

Is $\vec c$ still a eigenvector for $\lambda =2 $ ? If so,How to prove it?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are both eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue, then any non-zero linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is also an eigenvector for that eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  We have $M \vec a = \lambda \vec a$ and $M \vec b = \lambda \vec b$.  Following Gram Schmidt, we have $\vec c = k_1 \vec a + k_2 \vec b$ for scalars $k_1,k_2$. It follows that
$$
M \vec c = M(k_1 \vec a + k_2 \vec b) = k_1 (M\vec a) + k_2 (M \vec b) = k_1 \lambda \vec a + k_2 \lambda \vec b = \lambda(k_1 \vec a + k_2 \vec b) = \lambda \vec c
$$
So, $\vec c$ is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec a $ and $\vec b$ are two linearly independent eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue $\lambda$, this means that they are vectors of the same eigenspace that has dimension at least $2$. So in this space there is a vector $\vec c$ that is orthogonal to $\vec a$ and can be constructed using Gram-Shmidt from $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.
This vector is obviously  an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue, since it is an element of the same eigenspace (spanned by  $ \vec a$ and $\vec b$) .

But if we take another vector that is orthogonal to both $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ than this vector is not an element of the vector space spanned by $ \vec a$ and $\vec b$ so it is not in general an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue (and it is not an eigenvector at all, in general).

If the dimension of the eigenspace is $m>2$ then we have $m$ linearly independent eigenvectors that form a basis for the eigenspace, and we can apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to obtain $m$ orthogonal eigenvectors from these.